# how to copy a text and modify it before to paste it into an other column

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a code to copy an info from the column [3] and past it to the column [4]

here is the starting configuration :

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | "SUIVI DU TEMPS_LOUISE_RODRIG" |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | "SUIVI DU TEMPS_ANTHO_DACOSTA" |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

here is the final result :

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | "SUIVI DU TEMPS_LOUISE_RODRIG" | LOUISE_RODRIG |
|  |  |  |  | LOUISE_RODRIG |
|  |  |  |  | LOUISE_RODRIG |
|  |  |  |  | LOUISE_RODRIG |
|  |  |  |  | LOUISE_RODRIG |
|  |  |  |  | LOUISE_RODRIG |
|  |  |  | "SUIVI DU TEMPS_ANTHO_DACOSTA" | ANTHO_DACOSTA |
|  |  |  |  | ANTHO_DACOSTA |
|  |  |  |  | ANTHO_DACOSTA |
|  |  |  |  | ANTHO_DACOSTA |

This is the code I did :

```
function CREATE_NAME() {

  var COLsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA_COLLECT");

  
//copy name

  var suivname = COLsheet.getRange(5,4,COLsheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  COLsheet.getRange(5,5, suivname.length, 1 ).setValues(suivname);

//fill the empty lines
  var name = COLsheet.getRange(5,5,COLsheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  for( let i=1; i<name.length; i++ ) {
  if( name[i][0] === "" ) name[i][0] = name[i-1][0];
  }
  COLsheet.getRange(5,5, name.length, 1 ).setValues(name);

}
```

It's perfectly working, but if you watch my final result, I would like to have only the name and first name without the `"SUIVI DU TEMPS_` and the last `"`
and actually, my code only copy the same value that there is into the column [3].

Could anybody tell me how can I modify the value from `"SUIVI DU TEMPS_LOUISE_RODRIG"` to `LOUISE_RODRIG` before I copy it ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, at `if( name[i][0] === "" ) name[i][0] = name[i-1][0];`, the raw value of column "D" is used. By this, `SUIVI DU TEMPS_LOUISE_RODRIG` and `SUIVI DU TEMPS_ANTHO_DACOSTA` are directly used. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

In order to avoid this issue, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
COLsheet.getRange(5,5, name.length, 1 ).setValues(name);
```

##### To:

```
COLsheet.getRange(5, 5, name.length, 1).setValues(name).createTextFinder("SUIVI DU TEMPS_").replaceAllWith("");
```

- If your actual cell value is `"SUIVI DU TEMPS_LOUISE_RODRIG"` including the double quotes and you want to remove this, please modify it as follows.

  ```
    COLsheet.getRange(5, 5, name.length, 1).setValues(name).createTextFinder('SUIVI DU TEMPS_|"').useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith("");
  ```
- As another approach, how about the following sample script? From your showing script, I understood that you might want to retrieve the values from "D5" and want to add more 3 new rows.

  ```js
  function CREATE_NAME2() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA_COLLECT");
    var range = sheet.getRange("D5:D" + (sheet.getLastRow() + 3));
    var { values } = range.getDisplayValues().reduce((o, [d]) => {
      if (d && d != o.temp) {
        o.temp = d.replace(/SUIVI DU TEMPS_|"/g, "");
      }
      o.values.push([o.temp]);
      return o;
    }, { values: [], temp: "" });
    range.offset(0, 1, values.length).setValues(values);
  }
  ```

#### Testing:

When the above both scripts are run, the following same result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution using `createTextFinder` and a `forEach`. Review the comments in the code for more info regarding what was done.

```js
function CREATE_NAME() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA_COLLECT")
  var to_replace = "SUIVI DU TEMPS_";  // This is the text we will find and replace
  let rangeList = ss.createTextFinder(to_replace).findAll()
  
  rangeList.forEach(function (rangeList) {
    if (rangeList.getColumn() == 4) {
      var row = rangeList.getRow();
      var value = rangeList.getValue();
      var repl = value.toString().replace(to_replace, "") // Here we are removing  "SUIVI DU TEMPS_"
      var repl2 = repl.replace(`"`, ``) // Here we are removing the first "
      var repl3 = repl2.replace(`"`, ``) // Here we are removing the second "   
      ss.getRange("E" + row).setValue(repl3)  // Paste the new value to the target column
       }  
  });
}
```

Test this code and hopefully this works for you, I tried using the same columns and rows you used in your sample code, but I highly recommend doublechecking them. If you have any questions just let me know and I'll do my best to answer them :)

#### References

- [FindAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findall)
- [Replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)
- [Find and Replace](https://spreadsheet.dev/find-and-replace-google-sheets-textfinder-apps-script)